# How to retrieve the text on search bar after clicking pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

OK, So I went to google and Search 'A', then I clicked on page 2
After that, I cleared the search bar then click on page 3,
I noticed that 'A' went back in the search bar.

How did this happen, using jquery or javascript, how am I going to do it?

You can give me a hint, a short story on how to.

I am using serverside:true, and I have my own input type=text for search because I don't like the embedded search of jQuery Datatable

Thanks

Comment: Use a variable to store the value

Comment: You appear to have asked two questions.  To answer the Google question: When you click on a link "clicked on page 3", the url is replaced by the url of the link.   For google, each page link also contains the original search query, how many items/rows per page and which item/row to start at, eg: `q=abc123&num=50&start=50`.  So there's a bit of js on startup (or using server-side tech, I didn't check) which says: put the value of `q=` into the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your described case with Google search**, the "A" is actually part of the link to the page 3.

So when you erase the "A" from the search bar, it leaves the encoded value in the link to page 3.

Example:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=A&biw=1879&bih=1103&ei=ohaRW8OLCYiVlwS2iJDwDQ&start=20&sa=N
```

The `q=A` is your search value. The page then takes this value and puts it into the search bar when page 3 is loaded.